# Elements in Binary search tree in Haskell?

Tags: search, haskell, binary-search-tree

How can I search an element in a binary search tree in Haskell?
I defined my tree :

```
 data Tree a = 
     Null | 
     L a | 
     N (Tree a) a (Tree a) 
     deriving Show
```

I want to make a function that search an element in BST :

```
 findElem :: Tree a -> a -> Maybe a
 findElem tree n = ...
```

How can I make it?

Comment: A side note: `L a` is redundant, use `N Null a Null` instead for simplicity.

Comment: What definition of a BST are you using? Write it down. There should be nearly perfect one to one correspondence between its clauses and Haskell constructs.

Comment: You will need an `Ord` constraint, `findElem :: Ord a => BST a -> a -> Maybe a`.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in the comments, you should get rid of the `L` constructor and use `N Null x Null` instead. It will let you avoid having to code unnecessary special cases for leaf nodes.

`findElem` should then look something like this:

```
findElem :: Ord a => Tree a -> a -> Maybe a
findElem Null _ = -- ...
findElem (N l x r) y =
    case compare x y of
        LT -> -- ...
        EQ -> -- ...
        GT -> -- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can define the BST type below:

```
data BSTree a = Null | Node (BSTree a) a (BSTree a)
    deriving Show


findElem :: (Ord a) => a -> (BSTree a) -> Maybe a
findElem _ Null = Nothing
findElem x (Node Null y Null) 
 | x == y = Just x
 | otherwise = Nothing
findElem x (Node leftSubT y rightSubT) 
 | x == y = Just x
 | x < y = findElem x leftSubT
 | x > y = findElem x rightSubT
```

The find element process is pretty intuitive. If the element you seeking is less than the root, search the left sub tree. Otherwise, search right.